# Meaning of iot edge module icons in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-iot-edge

I would like to understand what is the meaning of the different icons for the iot edge modules in visual studio code.

I can see 3 kinds of icons :

Blue:

[image]

Green:

[image]

Green (running)

[image]

I can assume that the last one is when modules are running, but for the two others ?

Comment: Yes, the last one indicates the modules are running, and the first one indicates the modules are disconnected. For the second one, could you please let me know when you see this?

Comment: Actually I don't really know when or why. It just appears sometimes

Comment: Is the status always the second one, Or it becomes the second one for some seconds, then becomes the last one?

Comment: Actually I don't know it seems to be random.. That's why I asked the question I don't understand when or why.. For example at the moment, my modules are reported as offline (blue icon) but on my RPi with `iotedge list` I see they are running. What could be the problem ?